# Disabling or hiding the home and recents buttons in android navigation

Tags: java, android, uinavigationbar

My goal is to disable or hide the `home` and `recents` buttons hence forcing the user to press the back button to quit the app. Attached is a screenshot (edited via Photoshop) to show my desired user interface.
Is there anyway to do it?
My app won't be published to the Google Play Store.
I don't mind requesting specific permissions for this to be feasible.

Screenshot below:-

[image: Navbar example]

Comment: There is a way to do this on most devices, but it requires a development-level permission, meaning it has to be granted through ADB.

Comment: I want to do this only in my app not on all device